# Why is tetrachlorocuprate (II) yellow if it is high-spin?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, crystal-field-theory

From my knowledge of transition metal complexes, tetrahedral complexes generally have less splitting (compared to octahedral complexes) because they only involve four ligands are they aren't placed directly near any d-orbitals (unlike octahedral complexes). Furthermore, chloride is a weak-field ligand and therefore forms high-spin complexes. Both of these facts point to tetrachlorocuprate absorbing light of low energy (red to orange) and therefore being blue in colour (as blue is complementary to red in the colour wheel).

However, it is a yellow complex, suggesting that it absorbs high energy purple or violet light. I can't make any sense of this. Even if I factor in Jahn-Teller distortion, it shouldn't surpass that of hexaaquacuprate (II) which is blue in colour. Does this have to do with de-excitation? If so, what makes tetrachlorocuprate different from all other complexes?

Comment: I think it is a very complicated story. I think there is no single species but a mixture. See Stability and Electronic Spectra of the Copper(II) Chloro Complexes in
Aqueous Solutions, M. A. KHAN and M. J. SCHWING-WEILL in Google Scholar.